# autocommand within conditional autocommand

Tags: autocmd

I have an autocommand that is supposed to register a different autocommand whenever I enter a buffer where a certain condition is met:

```
let w:contextlist_open = 1

augroup LaunchShowContext
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter * 
        \ if (exists("w:contextlist_open") && w:contextlist_open == 1) 
            \ | :autocmd CursorHold * call ShowContext()
        \ | endif
augroup END
```

If I fire up another buffer and switch back and forth, I get `Error detected while processing CursorHold Autocommands for "*":
E580: :endif without :if:  endif`. I suspect this is because Vim thinks the `endif` belongs with the second autocommand rather than the first, and I'm not sure how to make it so that it goes with the correct one. I tried wrapping the `autocmd CursorHold * call ShowContext()` in parentheses, but that seems to give me other problems.

Comment: `I'm not sure how to make it so that it goes with the correct one` Use `execute`. The same goes to `normal`, `command` and a few other commands. This is directly mentioned in `:h :au` (and also `:h :normal` and so on), just read it until the end.

Comment: That becomes too messy. Better just call a function, that performs your checks and quits early if they fail.

Answer (score 4):

Use `:execute` like this:

```
augroup LaunchShowContext | au!
    autocmd BufEnter *
        \ if get(w:, 'contextlist_open')
            \ | execute 'autocmd! CursorHold <buffer> call ShowContext()'
        \ | endif
augroup end
```

But note (at least) three problems:

1) You examine window-variable `contextlist_open`, while expecting buffer-specific event `CursorHold` to fire. That could be frustrating if your buffer is shown in several split windows.

2) `unlet`-ting `contextlist_open` will not remove `au CursorHold`, as one would expect.

3) `execute` will run under global `augroup` context, so you still must find a way to prevent repeating `call ShowContext()`'s due to multiple `BufEnter` events. I put `au!` for simplicity, but that could potentially conflict with other plugins, so you probably should explore another solution (create another `augroup mygroup` then check if `exists('#mygroup#CursorHold#<buffer>')` etc.).