# Plugin conflicts over BufWinEnter Autocommands

Tags: vimrc, autocmd, vim-windows

I have vim-markdown and nerdtree installed. And everything was working fine until I added the following to my .vimrc (verbatim from the nerdtree readme)

```
" Open the existing NERDTree on each new tab.
autocmd BufWinEnter * if getcmdwintype() == '' | silent NERDTreeMirror | endif
```

Now everytime I run the vim-markdown command `:Toc` I get the error:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>54_Toc[39]..BufWinEnter Autocommands for "*"..function 192[2]..193[4]..203[15]..function <SNR>54_Toc[39]..BufWinEnter Autocommands for "*"..func
tion 192[2]..193[4]..203:
line    6:
E788: Not allowed to edit another buffer now
Error detected while processing function <SNR>54_Toc[39]..BufWinEnter Autocommands for "*"..function 192[2]..193:
line    4:
E170: Missing :endfor
```

Note that this error is triggered independently of the nerdtree window being open or not.

I tracked the error using the `:scriptnames` command.

The relevant code to this error seems to come from `vim-markdown/ftplugin/markdown.vim` which has the following:

```
ugroup Mkd 
    " These autocmd calling s:MarkdownRefreshSyntax need to be kept in sync with
    " the autocmds calling s:MarkdownSetupFolding in after/ftplugin/markdown.vim.
    autocmd! * <buffer>
    autocmd BufWinEnter <buffer> call s:MarkdownRefreshSyntax(1)
    autocmd BufUnload <buffer> call s:MarkdownClearSyntaxVariables()
    autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> call s:MarkdownRefreshSyntax(0)
    autocmd InsertEnter,InsertLeave <buffer> call s:MarkdownRefreshSyntax(0)
    autocmd CursorHold,CursorHoldI <buffer> call s:MarkdownRefreshSyntax(0)
augroup END
```

But surprisingly it doesn't make a difference if I comment the ButWinEnter line in it.

I found a couple of relevant threads [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27098/autosave-and-nerdtree-conflicts) and [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22086/autocommand-within-conditional-autocommand)
But can't really make something out of it that I can use to fix my problem.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem.
but for me, commenting the line blow works.

```
" Open the existing NERDTree on each new tab.
autocmd BufWinEnter * if getcmdwintype() == '' | silent NERDTreeMirror | endif
```

Maybe you should restart vim after commenting.

Otherwise, you can use [vim-nerdtree-tabs](https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs) to archive same result.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with RipGrep and NERDTree, the same error happened when I tried to use the :Rg command.
It was caused by BufWinEnter in the Quickfix buffer, so I fixed that by excluding it :

```
autocmd BufWinEnter * if getcmdwintype() == '' && &buftype != 'quickfix' | silent! NERDTreeMirror | endif
```

Not sure if it's the same problem for you.